# LESS: how to find wrong @import paths?

Tags: less

Sometimes I experience problems importing LESS files from multiple paths, resulting in webpages without style, but no feedback in page errors.

Surely problems depends on some errors in path declarations, especially when I import a file that imports another one in a nested structure.

I'm asking if there is any tool or tecnique to detect these errors in order to quickly find problems.

Answer (score 1):

If you compile your LESS code client side, env to `development` in the LESS object:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">less = { env: 'development' };</script>
  <script src="less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This will thrown an error if some imported file is missing:

[image]

Also the command line compiler (install with `npm install -g less`) generates an error:

`lessc less/styles.less`:

```
FileError: 'ixins.less' wasn't found in /home/bass/Dropbox/testomgeving/testdrive/book/02/less/styles.less on line 4, column 1:
3 @import "variables.less";
4 @import "ixins.less";
5
```